# Why laravel users get looged out everytime I deploy an app to heroku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku

We are using Laravel 5 and spatie-permissions package. Every time we commit something to the master branch, everything gets rebuilt.

Could that be the cause of invalidating all user sessions?

PHP version is 7.4.33. We used auth0 for user login earlier, should we remove it from composer.json?

I've attached the log below

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack  
-----> Using buildpacks:  
       1. heroku/php  
       2. https://github.com/harrylewis/heroku-buildpack-potrace.git  
-----> PHP app detected  
-----> Bootstrapping...  
  
 !     WARNING: Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!  
 !   
 !     The 'composer.lock' file in your project is not up to date with  
 !     the main 'composer.json' file. This may result in installation  
 !     of incorrect packages or package versions.  
 !   
 !     The lock file is required in order to guarantee reliable and  
 !     reproducible installation of dependencies across systems and  
 !     deploys. It must always be kept in sync with 'composer.json'.  
 !   
 !     Whenever you change 'composer.json', ensure that you perform  
 !     the following steps locally on your computer:  
 !     1) run 'composer update'  
 !     2) add all changes using 'git add composer.json composer.lock'  
 !     3) commit using 'git commit'  
 !   
 !     Ensure that you updated the lock file correctly, and that you  
 !     ran 'git add' on both files, before deploying again.  
 !   
 !     Please remember to always keep your 'composer.lock' updated in  
 !     lockstep with 'composer.json' to avoid common problems related  
 !     to dependencies during collaboration and deployment.  
 !   
 !     Please refer to the Composer documentation for further details:  
 !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/  
 !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md  
  
-----> Preparing platform package installation...  
-----> Installing platform packages...  
       - php (7.4.33)  
       - ext-oauth (2.0.7)  
       - ext-memcached (3.2.0)  
       - ext-imagick (3.7.0)  
       - ext-ftp (bundled with php)  
       - apache (2.4.57)  
       - composer (2.6.4)  
       - nginx (1.24.0)  
       - ext-gd (bundled with php)  
       NOTICE: detected userland polyfill packages for PHP extensions  
       NOTICE: now attempting to install native extension packages  
       Installing extensions provided by symfony/polyfill-mbstring:  
       - ext-mbstring...   
       Installing extensions provided by symfony/polyfill-iconv:  
       - ext-iconv...   
       Installing extensions provided by symfony/polyfill-ctype:  
       - ext-ctype...   
  
 !     WARNING: Your selected PHP version has reached end-of-life  
 !   
 !     No updates or security fixes have been provided for your PHP  
 !     version series by the PHP Group since 2022-11-28.  
 !   
 !     It is strongly recommended you update your app to a version of  
 !     PHP with "active support" status immediately to ensure you get  
 !     the latest bugfixes and security updates each time you deploy.  
 !   
 !     You may check the list of versions supported by the PHP Group  
 !     and their EOL dates here: http://php.net/supported-versions.php  
 !   
 !     For a list of supported runtimes & extensions on Heroku, please  
 !     refer to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support  
  
-----> Installing dependencies...  
       Composer version 2.6.4 2023-09-29 10:54:46  
       Installing dependencies from lock file  
       Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.  
       Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json.   You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.  
       Package operations: 135 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals  
         - Installing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.6.9): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.4.11): Extracting archive  
         - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.5): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.46): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/routing (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/process (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/mime (v5.4.13): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.46): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.13): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/log (1.1.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/debug (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/error-handler (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.46): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/finder (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/container (1.1.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/console (v4.4.45): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing egulias/email-validator (3.2.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100): Extracting archive  
         - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.9.6): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing opis/closure (3.6.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/translation (v4.4.45): Extracting archive  
         - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.39.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing monolog/monolog (1.27.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.10): Extracting archive  
         - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.9.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.8): Extracting archive  
         - Installing laravel/slack-notification-channel (v1.0.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/promise (1.1.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/httplug (v1.1.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (2.2.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/http-client (v5.4.13): Extracting archive  
         - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.4.6): Extracting archive  
         - Installing nexmo/client-core (1.8.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing nexmo/client (1.9.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing laravel/nexmo-notification-channel (v1.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.4.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing laravel/framework (v5.7.29): Extracting archive  
         - Installing firebase/php-jwt (v5.5.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing auth0/auth0-php (5.7.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing auth0/login (5.4.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing automattic/woocommerce (3.1.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing aws/aws-crt-php (v1.0.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing mtdowling/jmespath.php (2.6.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.238.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php-resources (0.3.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing clue/stream-filter (v1.6.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php81 (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/filesystem (v5.4.13): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/config (v4.4.44): Extracting archive  
         - Installing dzunke/slack-bundle (2.6.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing easypost/easypost-php (3.6.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing facebook/graph-sdk (5.7.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing gertjanspriensma/etsy-php (dev-master 95f0cb8): Extracting archive  
         - Installing http-interop/http-factory-guzzle (1.2.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing mmucklo/inflect (v0.3.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php (v2.2.15): Extracting archive  
         - Installing huddledigital/zendesk-laravel (v3.7): Extracting archive  
         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper (3.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.12): Extracting archive  
         - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.10): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing markbaker/matrix (3.0.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing markbaker/complex (3.0.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing myclabs/php-enum (1.8.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing maennchen/zipstream-php (2.2.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.16.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.25.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing maatwebsite/excel (3.1.25): Extracting archive  
         - Installing mixpanel/mixpanel-php (2.10.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing myparcelnl/sdk (v3.1.7): Extracting archive  
         - Installing omnisend/php-sdk (1.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing paypal/rest-api-sdk-php (1.14.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.6.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (3.0.16): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (v3.3.1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing phpclassic/php-shopify (v1.2.5): Extracting archive  
         - Installing picqer/sendcloud-php-client (v2.7.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/yaml (v4.4.45): Extracting archive  
         - Installing predicthq/address-formatter-templates (v1.0.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing mustache/mustache (v2.14.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing predicthq/address-formatter (v1.1.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing printnode/printnode-php (2.0.0-rc1): Extracting archive  
         - Installing psr/cache (1.0.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing starkbank/ecdsa (0.0.5): Extracting archive  
         - Installing sendgrid/php-http-client (3.14.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing sendgrid/sendgrid (7.11.5): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.26.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v5.4.11): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/message (1.13.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/discovery (1.14.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing php-http/client-common (1.11.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing jean85/pretty-package-versions (2.0.5): Extracting archive  
         - Installing sentry/sentry (2.5.2): Extracting archive  
         - Installing sentry/sdk (2.2.0)  
         - Installing sentry/sentry-laravel (1.9.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing setasign/fpdi (v2.3.6): Extracting archive  
         - Installing thecodingmachine/safe (v1.3.3): Extracting archive  
         - Installing setono/post-nord-php-sdk (v1.2.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing graham-campbell/guzzle-factory (v3.0.4): Extracting archive  
         - Installing spatie/dropbox-api (1.21.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing spatie/laravel-permission (2.38.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing stripe/stripe-php (v7.128.0): Extracting archive  
         - Installing tecnickcom/tcpdf (6.5.0): Extracting archive  
       Package dzunke/slack-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package facebook/graph-sdk is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.  
       Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.  
       Package laravel/nexmo-notification-channel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravel/vonage-notification-channel instead.  
       Package paypal/rest-api-sdk-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package predicthq/address-formatter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package predicthq/address-formatter-templates is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.  
       Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.  
       Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead.  
       Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.  
       Generating optimized autoload files  
       Class FedEx\Tests\ValidationAvailabilityAndCommitmentService located in ./vendor/jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/tests/FedEx/Tests/ValidationAvailabilityAndCommitmentServiceTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.  
       > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump  
       61 packages you are using are looking for funding.  
       Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!  
-----> Preparing runtime environment...  
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...  
-----> Potrace loaded app detected  
-----> Installing potrace  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/README-WIN  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/potrace.1  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/placement.pdf  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/README  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/NEWS  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/ChangeLog  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/mkbitmap.1  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/mkbitmap  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/AUTHORS  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/potrace  
potrace-1.16.linux-x86_64/COPYING  
-----> Discovering process types  
       Procfile declares types -> web, worker  
-----> Compressing...  
       Done: 186.1M  
-----> Launching...  
       Released v318  
       https://my-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku  
This app is using the Heroku-20 stack, however a newer stack is available.  
To upgrade to Heroku-22, see:  
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
```

Comment: Every time we deploy to Heroku, Laravel users get logged out likely because Heroku's ephemeral filesystem resets, deleting file-based sessions. To resolve this, switch your session driver in Laravel from file to a more persistent option like database or redis.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a bit confused, since the client didn't complain about logging out when he was using auth0.

Comment: @domaci_a_nas I am assuming you are using Laravel Passport, which uses the `database` driver, so it will never lose the session

Comment: @matiaslauriti, we never used Laravel Passport, but auth0/login. I am unaware that a package can use a separate session driver from the rest of the system, but I guess that's the reason why users weren't logged out earlier